# How to connect crystal report to MySql with SSL connection?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports, google-cloud-sql

Before, I was using this method to set my reports' connection info dynamically :

```
Public Sub LogOn(ByVal poReport As    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument, ByVal strServer As String, ByVal strTable As String, ByVal strUsername As String, ByVal strPassword As String)
    Dim loConnInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo
    loConnInfo.ServerName = strServer
    loConnInfo.DatabaseName = strTable
    loConnInfo.UserID = strUsername
    loConnInfo.Password = strPassword
    loConnInfo.IntegratedSecurity = False
    Dim loTables As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Tables
    Dim loTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table
    Dim loTableLogonInfo As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
    loTables = poReport.Database.Tables

    For Each loTable In loTables
        loTableLogonInfo = loTable.LogOnInfo
        loTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = strUsername
        loTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = strPassword
        loTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = strServer
        loTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = strTable
        loTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = False
        loTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(loTableLogonInfo)
    Next
End Sub
```

But now, I moved to google cloud sql which uses SSL connections with certificates so I have to pass the SSL connection information with cert too, I made a search for any SSL property or something else to assign, but I didn't find !

How to make Crystal Report connect to MySql instance with SSL connection and certificates by vb.net (I mean dynamically, not static connection) ?

Thanks